# Trying to migrate a Xaml designed project to Vb.net project with Windows form application

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to migrate a project designed with Xaml to Vb.net project with windows form application. I am using TreeNode class in windows form application while System.Windows.Controllar is TreeView in Xaml project. So I am getting an error in my code below, here is how best to fix the error. The line where I get the error is: `AddHandler treeViewItem.Expanded, AddressOf tvi_Expanded` where "Expression does not produce a value." I get an error

```vb
Private Function AddDirectoryNode(parentItemCollection As TreeNode,
                                  directoryDetail As DirectoryDetail) As Boolean
    Dim treeViewItem As TreeNode
    
    treeViewItem = New TreeNode()
    treeViewItem.Tag = directoryDetail
    
    AddHandler treeViewItem.Expand, AddressOf tvi_Expanded

    'If this Then directory contains subdirectories, add a placeholder
    If (directoryDetail.SubDirectoryDetails.Count() > 0) Then
        treeViewItem.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode() With {.Name = "placeholder"})
    End If
    
    'Add the treeview item into the items collection
    parentItemCollection.Nodes.Add(treeViewItem)
    
    Return True
End Function
    
Sub tvi_Expanded(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.ExpandNode(CType(sender, TreeNode))
End Sub
    
Private Sub ExpandNode(tvi As TreeNode)
    If (tvi.Nodes.Count = 1 And CType(tvi.Nodes(0), TreeNode).Name = "placeholder") Then
        tvi.Nodes.Clear()
        For Each directoryDetail As DirectoryDetail In (CType(tvi.Tag, DirectoryDetail).SubDirectoryDetails.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Path))
            Me.AddDirectoryNode(tvi.Nodes.Add(directoryDetail.Path), directoryDetail)
        Next directoryDetail
    End If
End Sub
```

Below is the original version:

```vb
Private Sub ExpandNode(tvi As System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem)
    If (tvi.Items.Count = 1 And CType(tvi.Items(0), System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem).Name = "placeholder") Then
        tvi.Items.Clear()
        For Each directoryDetail As DirectoryDetail In (CType(tvi.Tag, DirectoryDetail).SubDirectoryDetails.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Path))
            Me.AddDirectoryNode(tvi.Items, directoryDetail)
        Next directoryDetail
    End If
End Sub
        
Private Function AddDirectoryNode(parentItemCollection As System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection, directoryDetail As DirectoryDetail) As Boolean
    Dim treeViewItem As System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem
    Dim stackPanel As System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel
        
    ' Create the stackpanel and its content
    stackPanel = New System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel()
    stackPanel.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal
    ' Content
    stackPanel.Children.Add(Me.CreateProgressBar("Cumulative percentage from total used space {0}% ({1}))", directoryDetail.CumulativeSizePercentage, directoryDetail.FormattedCumulativeBytes))
    stackPanel.Children.Add(New System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock() With {.Text = directoryDetail.DirectoryName})
        
    ' Create the treeview item
    treeViewItem = New System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem()
    treeViewItem.Tag = directoryDetail
    treeViewItem.Header = stackPanel
    AddHandler treeViewItem.Expanded, AddressOf tvi_Expanded
        
    ' If this directory contains subdirectories, add a placeholder
    If (directoryDetail.SubDirectoryDetails.Count() > 0) Then
        treeViewItem.Items.Add(New System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem() With {.Name = "placeholder"})
    End If
        
    ' Add the treeview item into the items collection
    parentItemCollection.Add(treeViewItem)
        
    Return True
End Function

Sub tvi_Expanded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait
    Me.ExpandNode(CType(sender, System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem))
    System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the error message you get?

Comment: I've updated the question, can you check it this way?

Answer (score 1):

The TreeView control does not have one event matching `Expanded`. It has events for `BeforeExpand` and `AfterExpand`. It sounds like you want `AfterExpand`.

The arguments (types) that are sent to your handler `tvi_Expanded` will probably not match, so you need to change your handler sub and your event binder.

Example:

```
Private Function AddDirectoryNode()
'... change the binding for your event handler
   AddHandler treeViewItem.AfterExpand, AddressOf tvi_Expanded
'... etc
End Function

Private Sub tvi_Expanded(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) '
   Me.ExpandNode(e.Node) 'e.Node is the expanded TreeNode
End Sub
```

For more info, check the MS docs for TreeView.AfterExpand event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterexpand?view=windowsdesktop-7.0
and the TreeViewEventArgs obj https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treevieweventargs.node?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: I've updated the question, can you check it this way?

Comment: https://ibb.co/xY1GRpW  https://ibb.co/W2M4QY3  where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not `AddHandler TreeNode.AfterExpand` it needs to bind to an instance, like `AddHandler treeViewItem.AfterExpand`

Comment: https://ibb.co/7G7ryyn the result did not change

Comment: Oh I see it now. TreeNode is an object structure like DataTable or XMLNode. It doesn't have a UI component to respond to events. In WinForms TreeNode is used for populating a TreeView (UI) on a form. The events can only bind to the TreeView (which will handle TreeNode changes)

Comment: As you add to your TreeNode, I don't think you will need to attach more expand event handlers to each node. The TreeView will call `AfterExpand` each time and include the expanded node as an arg automatically.

Comment: https://ibb.co/wJvjPX2 Let's see if I got it right. Since it is a TreeView its node will be expanded automatically. Why don't you think I

Comment: Your TreeView will still need to call a AfterExpand (or BeforeExpand) to add TreeNodes to the expanding item. The control (UI) should pick up the changes and display.  So, are you still binding an event to the TreeView and adding child-nodes upon expand?